# Scrapy log.info in function

Tags: python, scrapy

It seems that Scrapy doesn't display log.info when calling callback.
My code:

```
import scrapy
import re
from array import *
import platform
print("version :"+platform.python_version())

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "test"
    start_urls = [
           'https://www.google.com'
           ]

    def parse(self, response):
        self.logger.info("before callback")
        scrapy.Request("http://www.google.de", callback=self.parseOther)
        self.logger.info("after parseOther")
        return

    def parseOther(self, response):
      self.logger.info("##################parseOther#######################")         
        return
```

Maybe the callback is not executed. Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Creating a `Request` is not enough for it to actually be sent.
You need to yield it, just like you would yield items.

```
yield scrapy.Request("http://www.google.de", callback=self.parseOther)
```

Comment: Thks for your answer.
...and sorry for the delay